# Linear maps with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

We consider the linear mapping
$${
\varphi: \Bbb R^3 \to\Bbb R^2
\\
v\to
\begin{bmatrix}  2&-1&1\\
  1&2&5
\end{bmatrix}v
}$$
Let us assume that
$B =\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $C =\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}$ are two introduced bases of $\Bbb R^3$ and $\Bbb R^2$, respectively. Determine the mapping matrices $A_{φ,B,S_2}$, $A_{φ,S_3,C}$ and $A_{φ,B,C}$, where $S_2$ and $S_3$ are the standard bases of $\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$, respectively.

Does anyone know how to do this? Am I supposed to put φ, the vectors of B and whatever is the standart base of R^2 into a single matrix? Will that be enough? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basis transformation over $\Bbb R^n$ from basis 1, say $B_1$, to basis 2, say $B_2$, is linear with the following mapping:
$$
{\psi_{\Bbb R^n}:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n
\\
v\to B_2^{-1}B_1v.
}
$$
The reason is obvious. The $B_1$ transformation resets the basis $B_1$ to the standard one, which is converted to basis $B_2$ through $B_2^{-1}$ transformation. An example comes with $n=3$, $B_1=I_3$ and $B_2 = \{(−1, 1, 0)^⊤,(1, 1, 1)^⊤,(0, 1, 1)^⊤\}$. In this case, we wish to convert the basis from the standard one to $B_2$. Obviously, we expect that the vector $\begin{bmatrix}−1& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ be converted to $\begin{bmatrix}1& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, since it is a basis vector in our new system of basis. It is so because
$$B_2^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0& 1 &-1\\
1& 1 &-1\\
-1 &-1& 2\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}0& 1 &-1\\
1& 1 &-1\\
-1 &-1& 2\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, to fulfill your question, we assume that the transformation $\varphi$ transforms $v$ to $w$, where $w=Tv$, in which
$$
T= \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
  2&-1&1\\
  1&2&5
\end{array}
\right].
$$
Since $v$ and $w$ are expressed in standard basis of their own space, a transformation of $B$ is needed to transform the $\Bbb R^3$ vectors expressed in basis $B$ to those expressed in the standard basis. The linear transformation of $T$ is now applicable to vectors $Bv$, where the result is expressed in standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ by the definition of $\varphi$. Finally, a linear transformation of $C^{-1}$ would finish the job, we ending up with a total transformation of $C^{-1}TB$.

Comment: So the standard basis is B2^-1? How do you transform vectors?

Comment: No. The standard basis is the identity matrix in $\Bbb R^n$, where $B_2^{-1}$ plays the role of basis transformation from the standard basis (which is $I_n$) to the basis of $B_2$ (where the columns of $B2$ represent the new basis for $\Bbb R^n$). This result is expected. To justify it, observe that the matrix $B_2^{-1}$ really transforms the columns of $B_2$ to $I_n$, because according to intuition, the first column of $B_2$ is the first basis vector in the new basis, the second column of $B_2$ is the second basis vector, and so forth.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. What does the identity matrix look like then?

Comment: That's fine. Just to be sure. Do you mean "What does the identity matrix look like **under the change of basis**"?

Comment: Yes, that is what i mean

Comment: The basis transformation affects separately on the columns of the identity matrix, so let's regard them one by one. Starting from $[1\quad 0\quad 0]$, this vector is a basis for $\Bbb R^3$ *in the standard basis*, but NOT in the $B_2$ basis. Actually, one can easily see that$$[1\quad 0\quad 0]=(1)\times[1\quad 1\quad 1]+(-1)\times[0\quad 1\quad 1],$$ where $[1\quad 1\quad 1]$ and $[0\quad 1\quad 1]$ are the 2nd and 3rd basis vectors in the $B_2$ basis. Similar analysis holds for $[0\quad 1\quad 0]$ and $[0\quad 0\quad 1]$, which can be expressed as the columns of $B_2$ (the new basis).

Comment: The result is that the vector $[1\quad 0\quad 0]$ in the standard basis becomes $[0\quad 1\quad -1]$ in the new basis.